# Grow 3ware raid 10 unit capacity

Tags: 3ware

I have a 3ware 9750-8i setup with a 22 disk raid 10. We need to expand the unit's capacity and so I have replaced every drive in the unit with a larger one in two passes. Currently the unit is showing as all ok, but it's still showing each subunit is 274.729 gigabytes rather then the new drive size of 931.51 gigabytes.

I've attempted to migrate the unit to the same raid level, but alas, it just refuses to do so.

My question is, how do I actually extend the unit/subunits to the extra available space?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so after a bunch of research, I decided to bite the bullet and just delete and re-create the unit and count on the controller doing the right thing, which it did. The raid unit re-assembled as synced on re-creation of the new array and I was able to extend the partition and expand the filesystem.

Comment: How long did your finger hover over the mouse button when confirming the action? ;)

Comment: At least 3 minutes, and that's after I verified the backups were all solid :)